# return type of bool function

Tags: boolean, boolean-operations

what is the return type of this sort of bool function...... i know the return type is either true of false but this seems complicated when you have got like this..

```
bool mypredicate (int i, int j) {
return (i==j);
}
```

this bool function are used in a library function called equal...... another example is....

```
bool compare(int a, int b){
return a<b;
}
```

so what are the perspective here to return type of these bool function.when is goes true & false....

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions `mypredicate` and `compare` are merely thin wrappers over the binary operators `==` and `<`. Operators are like functions: they take a number of arguments of a given type, and return a result of a given type.

For example, imagine a function `bool operator==(int a, int b)` with the following specification:

- if `a` equals `b` then return `true`
- otherwise return `false`

And a function `bool operator<(int a, int b)` with the following specification:

- if `a` is strictly lesser than `b` then return `true`
- otherwise return `false`.

Then you could write:

```
bool mypredicate (int i, int j) {
    return operator==(i, j);
}

bool compare(int a, int b){
    return operator<(a, b);
}
```

For convenience, most programming languages allow you to use a shorter, functionnaly equivalent syntax: `i == j` and `a < b`.